# Reroute pid output

Tags: linux, bash, stdout, background

Heyo all,

Say I have a bash file.

```
echo "Hey!"
echo "Hay!"
bash ~/otherstuff.sh &
```

It's the last line that annoys me. I'd like it to be done in the background, which it technically is. But every time it starts, it outputs `[1] 21345`, i.e. the process ID. I've tried every reroute I know of, none work.

TL;DR hide Procees output, and is it even considered an `stdout`?

The best I have is `sh -c '. ~/otherstuff.sh' & disown`, which hides the "completed" output, but not the original output.

Cheers! Bobbbay

Answer (score 1):

This `[1] 21345` is not from the process you run asynchronously, it's from the interactive Bash you're working in.

Non-interactive `bash` or `sh` should not write this, so let *it* run the task asynchronously:

```
bash -c 'whatever &'
# or
sh -c 'whatever &'
```

Notes:

- This will redirect stdin of `whatever` to `/dev/null` or equivalent file.
- The task will not become a job in the main shell (`jobs` will not list it), you won't be able to simply bring it to the foreground with `fg`.

To run `whatever &` as a job in the main shell without printing `[1] 21345` or so, you need to juggle file descriptors of the main shell. Bash prints `[1] 21345` to its stderr, we need to redirect it temporarily:

```
exec 12>&2 2>/dev/null; whatever & 2>&12; exec 2>&12 12>&-
```

Notes:

- This uses file descriptor `12`. Choose another number if it collides with anything you're doing (or use [`{varname}>…`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Redirections)).
- `whatever` will run with stderr restored.
- Any problem the main shell encounters while actually running `whatever` (e.g. `command not found`) will be silenced, because at the time the stderr of the shell is `/dev/null`.
- Still you will see `[1] Done` or so after the job finishes.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! Interestingly this is crashing my alacritty windows every time I run it. Ideas?

Comment: @Bobbay There are two distinct commands in my answer. Which one do you mean by "this"? Does "this" misbehave with any command? or only with `otherstuff.sh`? What does the script do? Do other terminal emulators crash?

Comment: The second command you wrote, using `zsh -c ". ~/.initrc"`. Same thing goes for any command in there, e.x. `echo "Hello!"`, this happens with xterm as well (I can try with your terminal emulator, if needed ;) )